# How to get selectable dynatree output as JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, model-view-controller, dynatree

I am have created a selectable JQuery Dynatree object, and now what I want are two things:

1. pass the Dynatree selection result into JSON and pass to another tree as a preview.
2. post the JSON format data from the form to call related web services.

Any advice will be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily see from the [documentation](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html) (and in the [samples page](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html)) that you can get all selected nodes by using `getSelectedNodes` as:

```
$("#tree").dynatree("getSelectedNodes")
```

This will get you an array of all selected nodes, which you can pass to your JSON object without tampering with this, as JSON access arrays.

To use a preview, you can check the **Drag'n'drop 3** sample.

Comment: thanks for this. I noticed getSelectedNodes, i thought that result will lose the actual tree structure after converted into JSON. will give it a try.

Comment: can u help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050635/json-tree-with-check-box-only-for-parent-object