# Json tree with check box only for parent object

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-plugins

what i am looking for is i have to add 
check box to the parent object of json only not for child json. Then i have to save the values of  parent json object.

```
    [
      {
        "tweetText": "P/s Q' 2013 K IPL Min Kis Batsamin Ni Sub Si Ziada Runs Bnay\n....03448972100",
        "urlsMentioned": [

    ],
    "usersMentioned": [

    ],
    "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/devices\" rel=\"nofollow\">txt</a>",
    "tweetId": 364239659250892800,
    "reTweetCount": 0,
    "reTweeted": false,
    "createdDate": "Mon Aug 05 09:51:16 IST 2013",
    "user": {
      "location": "Swat, Pakistan",
      "userId": 1558242139,
      "screenName": "ZaLiM_Shairi",
      "userName": "Best Forever S.FAHAD",
      "profileDescription": "Only for Sad and Romantic Poetry\r\nFollow\r\n@Zalim_Shairi &@Ghamgeen_Shairi\r\nS. Fahad & I. KHAN owners of Best Forever Group",
      "language": "en"
    },
    "hashTags": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "tweetText": "RT @ItsPsychoLOVE: Jangan mencintai seseorang yg tdk kamu percaya, tapi percayailah seseorang yg mencintaimu dan berusaha untuk menerimanya…",
    "urlsMentioned": [

    ],
    "usersMentioned": [
      {
        "userId": 856172684,
        "screenName": "ItsPsychoLOVE",
        "userName": "Open FollowBack :))"
      }
    ],
    "source": "<a href=\"http://blackberry.com/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for BlackBerry�</a>",
    "tweetId": 364239488811155460,
    "reTweetCount": 534,
    "reTweeted": true,
    "createdDate": "Mon Aug 05 09:50:36 IST 2013",
    "user": {
      "location": "",
      "userId": 1147194883,
      "screenName": "trianssa",
      "userName": "Anssa••",
      "profileDescription": "Ku tau kau tak tersenyum melihatku menangis. Maka sekuat tenaga ku relakan saat kepergianmu :,)",
      "language": "id"
    },
    "reTweetedStatus": {
      "tweetText": "Jangan mencintai seseorang yg tdk kamu percaya, tapi percayailah seseorang yg mencintaimu dan berusaha untuk menerimanya sepenuh hati. #IPL",
      "urlsMentioned": [

      ],
      "usersMentioned": [

      ],
      "source": "<a href=\"http://www.tweetdeck.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">TweetDeck</a>",
      "tweetId": 361389482198573060,
      "reTweetCount": 534,
      "reTweeted": false,
      "createdDate": "Sun Jul 28 13:05:41 IST 2013",
      "user": {
        "location": "In your hearts~",
        "userId": 856172684,
        "screenName": "ItsPsychoLOVE",
        "userName": "Open FollowBack :))",
        "profileDescription": "Bukan dengan kata2, tp dengan upaya yg dapat membuktikan sebuah kepercayaan. FOLLOW-� @ItsPsychoLOVE �- Dokter konsultasi percintaan (???)",
        "language": "id"
      },
      "hashTags": [
        "IPL"
      ]
    },
    "hashTags": [

    ]
  }
]`
```

In that above example i have 2 parent objects that has child objects. I want to add check box to the parent object currently i am using jquery.jsoneditor.js
http://www.daviddurman.com/jquery-json-editor-plugin.html

when i edited the code in js like
 `

```
function construct(opt, json, root, path) {
        path = path || '';

        root.children('.item').remove();

        for (var key in json) {
            if (!json.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

            var item = $('<div>', { 'class': 'item', 'data-path': path }),
                property = $(opt.propertyElement || '<input>', { 'class': 'property' }),
                value = $(opt.valueElement || '<input>', { 'class': 'value'    });

            if (isObject(json[key]) || isArray(json[key])) {
                addExpander(item);
            }

        if (isObject(json[key])) {
          item.append('<input type="checkbox">');
        }


            item.append(property).append(value);
            root.append(item);

            property.val(key).attr('title', key);
            var val = stringify(json[key]);
            value.val(val).attr('title', val);

            assignType(item, json[key]);

            property.change(propertyChanged(opt));
            value.change(valueChanged(opt));

            if (isObject(json[key]) || isArray(json[key])) {
                construct(opt, json[key], item, (path ? path + '.' : '') + key);
            }
        }
    }
```

It adds checkbox to the child object also. Is it possible to find if this is a parent object or not?  is that any way to add check box to parent only? Thanks in advance